# Access ng-model of other element from within directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which is supposed to update another input.

However, I cannot find a way to access the ng-model of the other input **from within the directive**

**accessOther directive**

```
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('accessOther', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
      // ngModel here only refers to the current input
      ngModel.$setViewValue('test');

      // how to get access/modify another input? (ie. #outside)
    }
  }
})
.controller('parentController', function() {
  var pc = this;
  pc.data = {};
})
.controller('nestedController', function() {
});
```

**In the below code, The accessOther directive is in #current but is trying to change #outside**

```
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="parentController as pc">
    <input type="text" ng-model="pc.data.parent" id="parent" placeholder="parent">

    <div ng-controller="nestedController as nc">
        <input type="text" ng-model="pc.data.outside" id="outside" placeholder="outside">
        <br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="pc.data.current" id="current" access-other placeholder="current">
    </div>
</body>
```

**plnkr:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/j34GKypDW4h6sZgsMCaA?p=preview

Additionally, is it possible to change **#parent** from within the directive too?

Comment: I can change all three inputs. I don't understand what you're trying to do. In general

Comment: @Ursus I am trying to change them from **within the directive**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check working demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZP55npGvm23g7AjcYuVV?p=preview).

Add this to the directive:

```
scope.$parent.pc.data.outside = 'changed `outside` from directive';
scope.$parent.pc.data.parent = 'changed `parent` from directive';
```

You can access the `parent scope` using `$parent` property on the directive scope object.